# Run .sh (from linux) scripts on windows using eclipse

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse, sh

I have a `.sh` scripts in Linux.

I want to create a form in Java (eclipse) **on Windows**

and execute those `.sh` files.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: maybe with http://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to be able to run those shell scripts on target computer. 
So try Cygwin, MinGW or other Unix emulators.

If run successfully next step is to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` for running script. You have to set up environment (run another command before) to make it working.

The gcc compiler on CDT Eclipse for Windows is working this way.

Answer (score 0):

`.sh` is a a shell script, most likely the default shell for a linux system, i.e. bash, so no, it won't run on your Windows machine. You can try Cygwin shell but still there is no guarantee that it will run. You will have to rewrite it for Windows batch script or your some other scripting language.

As far as Java is concerned, you can write in Linux and the code is portable to any other machine supporting JavaVM.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. Perhaps intalling Cygwin would be an option, but I would not recommend to go that way.
Or perhaps I misunderstood. If you like running those scripts on your linux-machine, you can trigger a remote execution easily by using the appropriate java commmands or libraries (eg: jssh or anything like that).

Comment: Can you give me more examples of libraries like jssh?